# non-whitespace before first tag. File MDAVSCLI?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I got this error while compiling my app I'm using Apache Cordova and visual studio 2015 as an IDE. I've looked for the MDAVSCLI file in my project but i can't find it. I think it's to do with the compliing the app on the android platform as when I run it on iOS I don't get the error.

The error I get is:

```
Description: Non-whitespace before first tag.   
Project:    C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Shake it up\Shake it up\MDAVSCLI
Line: 1
Column: 1   
Source: Build
```

I have no idea what to do and nothing I've looked at seems to be specific to my problem.

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution for this error?

Comment: I just started a new app on visual studio and copy and pasted my files to the new app works fine now!